# Where can I read Ruby's File.open function?

Tags: ruby

I'm going through "Learn Ruby the Hard Way" and I can't get my Windows command prompt to display the docs for: ri File.open

It just gives me an error:

ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..3)

I'm currently on exercise 16: http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex16.html

And the extra credit says: If you open the file with 'w' mode, then do you really need the target.truncate()? **Go read the docs for Ruby's File.open function and see if that's true.**

where can I see the docs for the File.open function?

Answer (score 5):

Read [the documentation of `IO`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html), `File`'s parent class. It describes the file opening modes you mentioned in your question. Here's the description for the `w` opening mode:

```
"w"  Write-only, truncates existing file
     to zero length or creates a new file for writing.
```

So no, you don't really need to call `target.truncate` if you open the file in `w` mode.

Answer (score 3):

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-open

Comment: ruby-doc has improved so much these years, and now there are even many examples. How come it is confusing?

Comment: Can you show me what comes up in the command prompt when you enter:  ri File.open  - I think if I see this, it will clear up a lot of questions for me

Answer (score 0):

How about using the ruby-doc.org site?